# Sequelize: Bind multiple models for join query and create custom columns

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to apply a join and groupBy in `Sequelize v5` that will fetch the records from five models [tables](https://dbdiagram.io/d/5ee8a8bc9ea313663b3a9f4a) and return the records as below format.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "products": {
        "id": "01",
        "name": "lorium",
        "description": "ipsum",
        "product_images": [
          {
            "url": "", // From images tbl
            "image_type": "Front" // From imge_types tbl
          },
          {
            "url": "",
            "image_type": "Back"
          }
        ]
      },
      "vendor": {
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created separate all five models and assign association to them.

*Product Model::*

```
const Product = SQLize.define('product', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, }
    product_title: { type: new DataTypes.STRING(255) },
    vendor_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED }
}); 
Product.hasMany(ProductImages, {foreignKey: 'product_id', targetKey: 'id', as :'product_img_refs'})

export { Product };
```

*Vendor Model::*

```
const Vendor = SQLize.define('vendor', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  first_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING(100) },
  last_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING(100) }
});
Product.belongsTo(Vendor, {foreignKey: 'id'})
Vendor.hasOne(Product, {foreignKey: 'id'})

export { Vendor }
```

*Product Images Model::*

```
const ProductImages = SQLize.define('product_images', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  product_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
  product_image_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
  img_type_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
});

export {ProductImages}
```

*Images Model::*

```
const ImagesModel = SQLize.define('images', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  img_url: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
});
export { ImagesModel }
```

*Image Types Model::*

```
const ImageTypes = SQLize.define('image_types', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  image_type: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
});
export { ImageTypes }
```

Below is the repository file on which i have performed the SQLize operation: Updated::

```
public async getProductData() {
  var prodData = Product.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: Vendor, as: 'vendor' }, 
      { model: ProductImages, as: 'product_img_refs' }
    ]
  });
  return prodData;
}
```

I am not getting the correct way to bind the all models that will return me a result as described in the above json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the nested output as shown in the question, you would need to create associations between the following:

- `ProductImages` and `ImagesModel`
- `ProductImages` and `ImageTypes`

Once done, you can nest the models in the `findAll` options as shown below:

```
// Create associations (depends on your data, may be different)
ProductImages.hasOne(ImagesModel);
ProductImages.hasOne(ImageTypes);

// Return product data with nested models
let prodData = Product.findAll({
    include: [
        { model: Vendor, as: 'vendor' },
        {
            model: ProductImages, as: 'product_img_refs',
            include: [
                { model: ImagesModel }, // Join ImagesModel onto ProductImages (add aliases as needed)
                { model: ImageTypes } // Join ImageTypes onto ProductImages (add aliases as needed)
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. you were trying to include `ProductImages` model into `Vendor`. As per your association, `ProductImages` associate with `Product` not with `Vendor`.

So please try this

```
let prodData = Product.findAll({
    include: [
        { model: Vendor, as: 'vendor' },
        { model: ProductImages }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hi @darshil, thanks for the lighting up this thing; i have already updated this model association into my question... actually i am looking for the solution to create a custom columns that i have shown in sample json format.